Identify group based usage when using Azure AD
In my web application, I am using azure AD for authentication and authorisation. I have app roles defined in the Azure AD app. The app roles are - superadmin, groupadmin and user. Different users can have different roles. A user can have more than one role as well.
Incrementally, now I want to identify how much each group is using my application, so that accordingly I can charge that group. A group is nothing but a way to cluster users coming from same department or unit or hub.
Following are the approaches which I tried and they did not work.
Approach 1: Create separate AD group for each department and assign different roles to different users in the AD group. Extract groupId from JWT access token to find the groupand send to application insights for group based aggregation.
Reason for failure: This did not work because roles can be assigned to users via Azure AD groups only. So, if superadmin, groupadmin and user are assigned to an AD group all the members of that group will get all the 3 roles. There is no possibility of assigning different roles to different users in the same group.
Approach 2: Assign department in the profile info of the user. Get user profile info of the logged in user from graph API and send to app insights for group based aggregation. No AD groups involved here.
Reason for failure: Due to organizational constraints cannot assign the department attribute to the user.
Approach 3: Create AD groups for each department and role. Assign the user to the required group accordingly. For example, AD groups would look like -. Finance-superadmin, Finance-groupadmin, Finance-user
Reasons for rejecting: Too much overhead of maintaining large no of groups.
Is there any other alternative approach that can be tried out to fulfill my requirement? Or is their any possibility to do some tweak in the above mentioned approaches?

Instead of relying on Azure AD groups or user attributes, you can implement a custom claims provider. This allows you to enrich the token with additional claims that can include department or group identifiers that are not directly tied to Azure AD groups. By doing this, you can maintain a mapping of users to their respective departments or units without needing to modify user attributes or create numerous groups.

Any update on the issue?


Note that: As an alternate approach, you can make use of you can add custom claims (like department or group) to the Azure AD access token.


This allows you to dynamically pass department/unit data without modifying the Azure AD structure.
Otherwise, if you need to work with groups then make use of dynamic groups based on user attributes can help automate the grouping process.
For instance, you can set up rules that automatically place users into groups based on current attributes (such as job title or location) without needing to modify their user profiles.

In the approach 3 you mentioned, managing a large number of groups for each department and role would be difficult to maintain.
Hence you can try making use of custom claim provider as detailed in this SO Thread by me.
Hence, custom claims provider will allow you to enrich the token with additional claims that can include department or group identifiers that are not directly tied to Azure AD groups.

You can maintain a mapping of users to their respective departments or units without needing to modify user attributes or create numerous groups.

Reference:
Customize tokens - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft
